# Click and actuate an <a> element JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, click

I wouldlike to actuate an  element with JavaScript, not only for call listeners, but also for open the link, like a user make with his mouse.
I search a lot in Google, Stack..., Mozilla, I alway find that it's not possible, but there must have a way to do it ^^
I search also for an advanced option in Mozilla to disable it or something like that, but I found nothing

The code that I wouldlike to work like a real user click :

```
<a href="www.mysite.com" id="MyIdElement">Click here</a>
$('#MyIdElement').trigger('click');
```

or

```
document.getElementById('MyIdElement').click()
```

I know that Mozilla doesn't allow a Javascript click event on a `<a>` element :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

`The click() method will not cause an <a> element to initiate navigation as if a real mouse-click had been received.`

I'm free to use another browser than Mozilla. My final aim is to make a browser add-on which navigate on webpage **absolutely** like a real user, and not with `windows.location.href` because this not sent all the informations like referer

Thanks

Comment: $('#MyIdElement').trigger('click'); works on Chrome.

Comment: @Valerio This doesn't work on Mozilla. On Chrome, is this executed like a real user click ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate an event mouse click (or others) directly on your dom element using the following script. This would simulate how an User will click on your link.

Live example, please note click on your link will be executed as soon as you page load:
https://jsfiddle.net/pogdmb3m/

This will work in Chrome and FireFox (circumnavigating its restriction).

```
var _triggerMouseEvent = function(node, eventType) {
  // create a syntetic mouse event
  var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
  clickEvent.initEvent(eventType, true, true);
  // dispatch event on your dom element
  node.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
};

var elmDom = document.getElementById('MyIdElement');

_triggerMouseEvent(elmDom, 'click');
```

Comment: This is exactly what I look for. Do you know why Mozilla and other browsers disable the "real click for navigate to a webpage" on trigger the "click" event on an `<a>` element ?

Comment: @dada17xs IMO for security reasons. But I could not find reference in any documentation so take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to trigger a java script function when clicking the "a" element. With the following code you will generate an alert when clicking on the "a" element and load the google site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
        function myFunction(){
            window.alert("Test");
            };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="http://google.com" onclick="myFunction()">Go to Google</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

The whole thing is run through this code block `onclick="myFunction()"`, it simply run the defined function by a click. I'm sure this is working on Chrome and IE. If I understand your question wrong please correct me and I will try to answer it correctly.